# Using downloaded image from server as imageview's background

Tags: android, download

> my xml code is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click To Download File"
        android:id="@+id/downloadButton"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

my class is;

```
public class DownloadFromServer extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button downloadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
String downloadServerUri = null;
Drawable drawable;
final String downloadFileName = "share.png";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_from_server);

    downloadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
    messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    downloadServerUri = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"+downloadFileName;

    downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DownloadFromServer.this, "", "Downloading File...",true);

            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("downloading started....");                             
                        }
                    });

                    downloadFile(downloadServerUri, downloadFileName);
                    image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });       
}
public void downloadFile(String sourceFileUri, String fileName){

    try{
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
        File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath());
        if(dir.exists()==false) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        URL url = new URL(sourceFileUri); //you can write here any link
        File file = new File(dir, fileName);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "download begining");
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "download url:" + url);
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);

        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        ucon.setUseCaches(true);
        drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(ucon.getInputStream(), "image1");
        ucon.connect();

        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
           baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
           Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
           dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

> i tried to take an uploaded image from server with name share.png, and i want to use that image as my ImageView's background. But, my problem is that, i can not use setImageDrawable() or setBackground() in any thread. The program is failed with that error: **"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch this view."**
>   How can i fix that error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the button click as below :

```
downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DownloadFromServer.this, "", "Downloading File...",true);

            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("downloading started....");                             
                        }
                    });

                    downloadFile(downloadServerUri, downloadFileName);
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

or

```
downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DownloadFromServer.this, "", "Downloading File...",true);

            final Handler handler=new Handler();

            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("downloading started....");                             
                        }
                    });

                    downloadFile(downloadServerUri, downloadFileName);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

The above code will update the image view with the drawable in the UI thread and everything will be good..

Answer (score 0):

You are updating/accesing ui from the background thread which is not possible. You should update/access ui on the ui thread.

Move it inside `runOnUiThread`

```
      image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

You can also use `AsyncTask` to avoid confusion.

Use `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` to update ui. Do your downloading in `doInBackground`. The result of `doInBackground` computation is param to `onPostExecute`. Receive result in `onPostExecute` and update ui.

AsyncTask docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button downloadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
String downloadServerUri = null;
Drawable drawable;
final String downloadFileName = "share.png";
ImageView image;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    downloadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
    messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    downloadServerUri = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"+downloadFileName;

    downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new DownLoadTask().execute();
        }
    });       
}

class DownLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Downloading File...",true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        downloadFile(downloadServerUri, downloadFileName);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

}
public void downloadFile(String sourceFileUri, String fileName){

    try{
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
        File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath());
        if(dir.exists()==false) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        URL url = new URL(sourceFileUri); //you can write here any link
        File file = new File(dir, fileName);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "download begining");
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "download url:" + url);
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);

        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        ucon.setUseCaches(true);
        drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(ucon.getInputStream(), "image1");
        ucon.connect();

        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
           baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
           Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
           dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

SnapShot

[image]

Comment: i do that but my drawable is null now, so there is no image on screen.

Comment: @Droid you are not doing it properly that's why its null use asynctask

Comment: Can't this be done with the method `ImageOperations` before the `setImageDrawable` (because it uses context)? Just as a second opinion?

Comment: it can be another solution, but i solve that problem with another answer. thanks anyway.

Comment: @Droid use asynctask as above i updated my post with the code

Answer (score 0):

```
loadImage(url);



void loadImage(String image_location) {

    URL imageURL = null;
    if (image_location != null) {
        try {
            imageURL = new URL(image_location);
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);// Convert to
                                                                // bitmap
            ivdpfirst.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        ivdpfirst.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.id.ivdpfirst));

    }
}
```